# unable to connect to Redis cluster using stackexchange.redis

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis, amazon-elasticache

I have found a very simple block of code to test if I'm able to connect to my Redis Cluster on ElastiCache

Here is the code:

```
using StackExchange.Redis;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("xxxxx.xxxxx.ng.0001.euw2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379,connectTimeout=30000,responseTimeout=30000,ssl=true,sslProtocols=tls12");

IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
string value = "abcdefg";
db.StringSet("mykey", value);

string value1 = db.StringGet("mykey");
Console.WriteLine(value1);
```

This is the error I get:

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException HResult=0x80131500
> Message=It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). Error
> connecting right now. To allow this multiplexer to continue retrying
> until it's able to connect, use abortConnect=false in your connection
> string or AbortOnConnectFail=false; in your code.
> Source=StackExchange.Redis StackTrace: at
> StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectImpl(ConfigurationOptions
> configuration, TextWriter log, Nullable`1 serverType,
> EndPointCollection endpoints) at
> StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigurationOptions
> configuration, TextWriter log) at Program.
>
> $(String[] args) in
> C:\Users\tracy\source\repos\stackexchangeRedis.test\stackexchangeRedis.test\Program.cs:line
> 5

**So I added in "`abortConnect=false`", and now this is the new error:**

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException HResult=0x80131505
> Message=Timeout performing SET (5000ms), inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, aw:
> False, bw: CheckingForTimeout, rs: NotStarted, ws: Idle, in: 0,
> serverEndpoint: XXXXX.XXXX.ng.0001.euw2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379, mc:
> 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName:
> TRACY(SE.Redis-v2.6.66.47313), IOCP:
> (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER:
> (Busy=0,Free=32767,Min=8,Max=32767), POOL:
> (Threads=9,QueuedItems=0,CompletedItems=37), v: 2.6.66.47313 (Please
> take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that
> can cause timeouts:
> https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
> Source=StackExchange.Redis StackTrace: at
> StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message
> message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server, T
> defaultValue) at Program.
>
> $(String[] args) in
> C:\Users\XXXX\source\repos\stackexchangeRedis.test\stackexchangeRedis.test\Program.cs:line
> 10

**Useful information:**

DotNet version: 6.0

StackExchange.Redis version: 2.6.66

I'm using visual studio 2022 on my local machine.

Redis cluster config:
[elasticache config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06sHC.png)

Comment: Have you seen this? [Accessing ElastiCache resources from outside AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/accessing-elasticache.html#grant-access)

Answer (score 2):

From the picture you sent, it seems that encryption in transit is disabled but the code you sent has `ssl=true`. You have to recreate the cluster with TLS enabled on change your client code not to use TLS.